# Installing .Net 3.5 SP1 framework company wide

Tags: windows, .net-3.5, deployment

We really want to start pushing-out products using the 3.5 framework but it is a pain having to install the framework on every PC.

We can get the app to do and automatic update on first run but that takes forever.

Is there any way to force all the PC's to update overnight? e.g. via Windows Update...

Our PCs are a mix of XP and Vista

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push the MSI through a policy. See some ideas [here.](http://documentation.commvault.com/commvault/release_7_0_0/books_online_1/english_us/deployment/install/msi_with_active_directory_group_policy.htm#Install_Procedure)

Answer (score 2):

Place the MSI in a Group policy.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using Microsoft's Systems Management Server ([SMS](http://www.microsoft.com/SMServer/default.mspx)) and [Software Update Services Feature Pack](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sms/bb676802.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Publish your installation by group policy, to do so, you only need an MSI version of the program, and you have to have access to group policy management console, when you do so, you only have to add new entry under the software installation menu (i forgot the exact name of the option), you can also uninstall it later the same way you installed it

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

Download [pstools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) and run psexec for remote install

example:-

psexec \workstation64 -c “c:\folder\dotnetfx35.exe” /q /norestart